# Recyclerview: can't get the item count value

Tags: android-recyclerview

im newbie here... I have a problem in getting the item count on my recyclerview? I've try this code but it's not working.

```
 int count = 0;
 if (recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter() != null) {
 count = recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter().getItemCount();
 }
```

also this one but it's not working too..

```
   int count = 0;
   if (mAdapter != null) {
   count = mAdapter.getItemCount();
   }
```

this is my code:

mainActivity:

```
private List<NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter> navList= new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NavDrawerFleetAdapter mAdapter;
Button add;
TextView successCount;

     protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer_fleet);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    add = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    successCount=findViewById(R.id.count);
    recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.nav_sent);
    mAdapter = new NavDrawerFleetAdapter(navList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  if (recyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
  successCount.getText(recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter().getItemCount());
 } 

       add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter navD= new 
        NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter(lati,longi,dateTime);
        navList.add(navD);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

myGetterSetter:

public class NotSentModuleGetterSetter {
    String lat,lon,dateTime;

```
public NotSentModuleGetterSetter(String lat, String lon, String dateTime) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(String lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}
```

}

```
myOutput:
```

[image]

as you see, the success count was turned into zero.
btw, my data was getting on my database and i was pickup the code need since i have a bunch of codes as for now for my project.

an also, using debug, the data of my mAdapter=null.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post RecyclerView Adapter class code and (partial) activity code in which how you're setting the ArrayList and adapter to the RecyclerView.

Comment: Probably the issue could be you are trying to get the item count before populating your adapter with data.

Comment: my data was live means every second has an update.. is it possible to get a live feedback count from recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i was getting the count data on my adapter but it should be get the "Size" of adapter than getting the "count". It is now working on me. :)